# QGIS3 - Join by location (falsely) adds neighbouring polygons

Tags: qgis

I have two layers:
Layer 1 - containing municipalities of country X in the year 2014 (around 600) 
Layer 2 - containing municipalities of country X in the year 2018 (around 500)

Between 2014-2018 several municipalities have merged. E.g. municipality A, B and C in the 2014 layer no longer exist in 2018 but are now part of municipality D.

I want to know for each 2014 municipality what its corresponding 2018 municipality is. So for municipality A, B and C the outcome should be D.

[image]

[image]

I tried to achieve this by performing Join by Location (using intersect). I would expect the joined layer to have 600 features (i.e. the number of 2014 municipalities) with a new attribute containing the corresponding 2018 municipality. However, the joined layer I get has over 2400 features. Municipality A is present 4 times, one entry has municipality D as new attribute (as expected) but the other 3 entries have the neighbouring municipalities of A as new attribute (E, F and I). I.e. QGIS seems to think that municipality A does not only intersect with D but also with all neighbouring municipalities of A.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Both layers have the same CRS.

Edit: Found out that if I zoom in a lot (ratio 85:1) there's a small difference between the two layers. I guess this causes the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to do the following:

- Generate the centroids of the polygons of 2014
- Spatially join the centroids with the polygons of 2018
- Join by attribute the polygons of 2014 with their centroids

I hope this would help.

Comment: To add to this Intersection includes where the boundaries of a pair of polygons overlap (what you think of as touching).

Answer (score 2):

Set it up the following:

- As `input layer` choose your old municipalities (2014).
- As `join layer` choose your new municiplaities (2018).
- As `geometric predicate` choose overlaps, within and equals.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Of course this will only work if the actual boundaries did not move.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but unfortunately still get 2500+ features. When I zoom in a ridiculous amount (85:1!) I can see that there's a small difference between the borders of the two layers. I guess that's the cause of this issue..

Comment: yes, this only works when the border lines stay the same and just the area allocation changed. In your case you will then probably get a better result with centroids (or pointonsurface) as @MohannadAdham suggested.